Why isn't my Google Sheets macro for adding today's date working?
In google sheets, I want to add a button that will contain a macro to add today's date. this date after the formula will be copy pasted so that it cannot change.
This was the "macro"
function Approved() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TODAY()');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};

but the date is not added and I am not sure why.

First, a simple script that writes a timestamp to the current cell.
function insertTimeStamp() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().setValue(new Date());
}

The displayed value depends on the cell formatting. If you select a cell and look at the formula bar, it will display something like this.
8/27/2024 9:42:55

To add a date (without the time part), try the below proposal:
function insertDate() {
  const timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, dateFormat);
  SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().setValue(date);
}

The value displayed in the formula bar will be
2024-08-24

The data type might be automatically set as a date, depending on your spreadsheet settings. If it's not set as a date, change the date format in the script to one supported by your spreadsheet.
Regarding why your script doesn't work, it is because the Apps Script engine apply all the changes once the script finishes. To fix your script add SpreadsheetApp.flush() before reading the cell as shown below
function Approved() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TODAY()');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};


Found it.
The formula to add a script that will add today's date and copy paste it in one macro so it cannot be changed.
function insertTodaysDate() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
cell.setValue(new Date());
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}


I'm glad that you was able to find a script that does what you need. It's worth noting that the last statement, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);, is not required.

Also, it's worth noting that the script doesn't include a formula. Please bear in mind that Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as a programming language. Please consider spending some time learning the basics of the programming language.

This was wrong advice, I removed the line mentioned and the function didn't work.
